# How to "break" out of urllib read

Tags: python, urllib

I want to stop `read` when an url has been opened if certain event occurs. Problem is, I don't know how to do it.
For instance:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')
readData = data.read() # How do I stop the reading if certain event occurs?
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what event are you expecting.

Comment: Hmm, well, I'm running it in a thread, so if certain flag is changed, I want the reading to stop. I can do that for when I'm writing to a file, because I'm buffering by certain block-size, and so I can break out of the buffer loop, but not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` takes argument how many bytes read once. E.g. `data = read(4096)` only reads 4 kB once. Read data in slices and after each slice check for the break condition. Or run the read loop in a different thread if this is not acceptable option.

It should look something like this in pseudo-Python:

```
import urllib2

CHUNKSIZE = 4096

r = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org')

buffer = b''

while True:
    chunk = r.read(CHUNKSIZE)
    if not chunk:
        break
    if bad_thing_happened:
        break

    buffer += chunk
```

Comment: Amazing! This is python 2, right? In python 3 it complains because the chunks are in binary, and so it can't append it to the buffer string. Changing `buffer = ''` to `buffer = b''` does the trick. Thank you.